# RestKit property relationship by ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Without using Core Data, how can I configure RestKit to map a ID that is a foreign key to another object? Basically I want to do what `RKConnectionDescription` does but without the Core Data part.

Considering the following two endpoints and JSON responses:

`GET /users/:userID`

```
{
  "user" : {
    "name" : "Bob Loblaw"
    "group_id" : "2"
  }
}
```

`GET /groups/:groupID`

```
{
  "group" : {
    "id" : "2"
  }
}
```

When I load my User object I want its `group` property to be mapped to the result of `GET groups/:groupID` based on the `user.group_id` JSON key path. Is this possible? How can I describe a relationship that involves requesting another resource to satisfy the property mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it during the mapping because without Core Data RestKit has no way to locate the object at the other end of the desired foreign key mapping.

So, in the success block you would need to find the appropriate object and make the connection yourself.

Comment: If you have relationships it would be natural to put that into Core Data. Is there a reason you don't want to?

Comment: mainly because it seemed to be an unnecessary complexity. When I map relationships via Core Data it seems the Group object had to exist in the persistent store before the property could be mapped successfully. Maybe I am just missing something but I had to seed/request every Group object so that they get persisted in Core Data before requesting my User object. The User's group property was nil unless I requested each group object before I requested the User. Does that seem right?

Comment: You can create a mapping for the group relationship which will create a stub object if it doesn't find an existing object. Then when you request the group it would complete the stub.

Comment: Depends on the app. It gives you the list of objects you need to request for your current users...